# Can i add custom keyboard to the core keyboard?

Tags: android

Hey this is a simple question but i can't seem to find an answer for it.

I'm intrested in creating something like a smilies keyboard to be added to the native keyboard so a person can add them in emails/SMS etc.

Now i guess i can edit the OS itself and add it to keyboard, but i was wondering if i can attach to the event that opens the keyboard and edit it?

Again, i'm **NOT** intrested in a custom keyboard inside my app, i want while my app is open (if possible without, better) to change the regular keyboard.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i was wondering if i can attach to the event that opens the keyboard and edit it?

No, sorry. That is a different application than yours; you cannot change it at runtime.

You are welcome to build your own input method editor and use that, though. Or, perhaps you could make a contribution to some existing open source input method editor project.